# Zariski Topology Closure of Unit Ball

Tags: general-topology

I'm attempting to understand a topology problem. The problem is

"What is the closure of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the Zariski topology?"

From my understanding, closed sets in the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the sets $C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : p_1(x)=0,...,p_k(x)=0\}$ where the $p_i$'s are polynomials. But for the closure we would need infinitely many points and I can only see the closure having finitely many points. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Before starting the exercise, did you try writing down one or two examples of Zariski closed set in, say, $\Bbb R^2$? Your (seemingly wrong) finiteness argument makes me think that it might have been instructive.

Comment: I plotted an example in mathematica and see where my mistake was, I had my mind in just one dimensional space, thanks!